# The startLeScan Method is not getting any results

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

The startLeScan method does seem to be working, I even made sure to put all the permissions in my manifest. I tried scanning several times however the app stopped working.

I have tried scanning for virtual beacons using another phone with the app Beacon Simulator. Each time the app crashed and stopped working.

```java
private void Scanner(){
    mAdapter.startLeScan(mLe);
}

private void stopScan(){
    mAdapter.stopLeScan(mLe);
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLe = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice Device, final int rssi, byte[] bytes) {
        list.add(Device.getName());
    }
};
```

I expected to get the beacons name but instead the app stopped working.